# Custom REST API returns duplicate "response" tag

Tags: magento2, api, xml, rest-api, response

I am struggling because I get an invalid response from my custom API module for Magento 2 (2.2.5). When I send a request to my endpoint via GET with the header **"Accept application/xml"** (which is totally valid for Magento 2) I get my XML reponse. However, the surrounding `<response>` tag pops up twice and I can't get rid of the second one. Here is a sample result:

```
<response>
    <test>value</test>
    <response/>
</response>
```

Problem here is the `<response/>` in line 3. Where does this come from/how can I get rid of this?

I'll only point out the most important files since the rest is just bare standard. For testing purposes I set the resource to anonymous (it's local so no worries here).

**webapi.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/xmlorderexport/get" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\XmlOrderExportApi\Api\XmlInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**Api/XmlInterface.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\XmlOrderExportApi\Api;

interface XmlInterface
{

    /**
     * Returns order data as XML.
     *
     * @api
     * @return string Returns the order as XML based on the given template.
     */
    public function get();
}
```

**Model/Xml.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\XmlOrderExportApi\Model;

use \Vendor\XmlOrderExportApi\Api\XmlInterface;
use \Vendor\XmlOrderExport\Model\WebapiInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Xml as Renderer;

class Xml implements XmlInterface
{

    private $webapi;

    private $renderer;


    function __construct(
        WebapiInterface $webapi,
        Renderer $renderer
    )
    {
        $this->renderer = $renderer;
        $this->webapi   = $webapi;
    }

    /**
     * Returns order data as XML.
     *
     * @api
     * @return string Returns the order as XML based on the given template.
     */
    public function get()
    {
        /**
         * Only for testing purposes!
         */
        //$order_id = 194;

        //$result = $this->webapi->getXml($order_id);
        //$xml    = simplexml_load_string($result);

        $this->renderer->render(['test' => 'value']);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me out and point me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance ...